# Mysql update multiples conditions make slow

Tags: mysql, sql

Im running this update, but MySQL take so long to do it, around 2 minutes. They are 36 conditions to do it.

My update is like this:

```
UPDATE table
SET delete = NULL
WHERE date > '2016-11-20 00:00:00' AND  (t.text LIKE '%text1%')
OR (t.text LIKE '%text2%')
OR (t.text LIKE '%text3%')
OR (t.text LIKE '%text4%')
OR (t.text LIKE '% text 5%')
...
...
...
...
OR (t.text LIKE '%text36%')
```

The update its done ok, but it's take so long, ¿any idea how can i optimize it?

Comment: How about running them separately with less conditions to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, fix the query (as Jorge suggests):

```
UPDATE table
    SET delete = NULL
    WHERE date > '2016-11-20 00:00:00' AND
         (t.text LIKE '%text1%' OR
          t.text LIKE '%text2%' OR
          t.text LIKE '%text3%' OR
          t.text LIKE '%text4%' OR
          t.text LIKE '% text 5%'
          ...
          t.text LIKE '%text36%'
         );
```

It may not be a big improvement, but `regexp` might be faster:

```
UPDATE table
    SET delete = NULL
    WHERE date > '2016-11-20' AND
         t.text REGEXP 'text1|text2|text3| . . .  |text36';
```

The only index that will help is on `date`.  I would suggest `table(date, text)`.  The `date` condition looks very selective.

Finally, you might find that a full text index will work on `text`.  That depends on the logic actually being executed (are the "text" patterns words, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE table
SET delete = NULL
WHERE (date > '2016-11-20 00:00:00') AND  (t.text LIKE '%text1%'
OR t.text LIKE '%text2%'
OR t.text LIKE '%text3%'
OR t.text LIKE '%text4%'
OR t.text LIKE '% text 5%'
...
...
...
...
OR t.text LIKE '%text36%')
```

Comment: **LIKE '%text'** is always a full table scan. So you CANT speedup it with an index